# htaccess and redirection to a holding page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'd like to redirect all outside visitors to a holding page whilst allowing all internal users to see the whole site.

I have the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^1.1.1.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/holding-page/index.php$
RewriteRule .* /holding-page/index.php [R=302,L]
```

Which does what I want but the holding page won't pull through any styling or images.

Does anyone know who I'd achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve by allowing access to the /holding-page/ directory with the following rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/holding-page/
```

Answer (score 0):

That is due to the use of relative links on your holding page.

Insert one more rule to fix that:

```
RewriteRule ^holding/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

If that doesn't fix the problem you can adapt these:

- use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
- You can add this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />`